# Change gContextMenu flags in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

In my extension I need, under certain circumstances, to display the context menu as if it had been clicked on a different element. E.g: I right-click on a certain element on a page, but the context menu should be displayed as if under the cursor there wasn't the element above, but rather a different element I specify.

I tried doing this in the popupshowing handler this by:

```
window.addEventListener( "load", function() {
    var contextMenu = document.getElementById("contentAreaContextMenu");
    if (contextMenu) {
        contextMenu.addEventListener("popupshowing", function(event) {
            if (document.popupNode !== newElement) {
                event.preventDefault();
                synthesizeMouse(newElement, 2, 2, { type: "contextmenu", button: 2 }, newElement.ownerDocument.defaultView);
            }
        }, false);
    }
}, false );
```

newElement is the element that should be "clicked on", and synthesizeMouse is defined [here](https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/test/test_contextmenu.html?force=1). Unfortunately, it doesn't work (if I actually click on newElement the context menu is shown correctly, if I click anywhere else the context menu is not shown at all). Can anybody see why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a bit of a wild guess, but because you're doing this while the context menu from the first event is already opening, maybe this is is blocking the context menu from opening again. Try sending the event 10ms later, so that the original context menu has already closed.

Comment: Yes, this works! Now I just have a little problem, i.e. the context menu is opened right on newElement, instead of the place where the pointer currently is. (What I'm trying to do is showing the context menu that would appear clicking on newElement regardless of where I click on the page)

Comment: This is because you're synthesizing the mouse over the new element ([2, 2] specifically). I don't think you can actually send a mouse event to a point that's not over the new element.

Comment: I found a way to do it: calling `document.getElementById("contentAreaContextMenu").moveTo(x, y);` after the `synthesizeMouse` call.

Comment: Ah yes, I had that idea myself, but I was away from the PC and forgot to note it down.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set `document.popupNode` to your element, call `gContextMenu.init(contextMenu, gBrowser);` and then clear `document.popupNode` again?

Comment: You probably meant either new nsContextMenu(contextMenu, gBrowser) or gContextMenu.initMenu(gBrowser). Unfortunately, neither are working. I probably need to dispatch some kind of event, but I have no clue about which one or how to send it.

Comment: @CAFxX I'm not sure why gContextMenu isn't set when your popupshowing event listener fires. What happens if you just set document.popupNode?

Comment: @Neil, gContextMenu is set - the problem is there is no function init. This is also verifiable by looking at the source code (https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/nsContextMenu.js): as I said above you were probably referring to either `new nsContextMenu(contextMenu, gBrowser)` or `gContextMenu.initMenu(gBrowser)`

Comment: @CAFxX you're right I was looking at the wrong version of nsContextMenu.js and I meant `gContextMenu.initMenu(gBrowser)`.

Comment: @Neil, unfortunately it doesn't work (no context menu is shown and no error is reported in the error console). I think that beside calling initMenu I should fire some kind of event but I have no idea about which one to fire (and what element to fire it on, or which parameters to use)

Comment: @CAFxX Odd. You're not doing something silly like calling event.preventDefault() or returning false are you?

Comment: I'm calling event.preventDefault() (as can be seen from the snippet in the question...) because I can't assume that my event handler will be called first, so other event handlers might already have run using the current gContextMenu. If I simply reinit the gContextMenu the following handlers will get the new one, but the previous handlers won't be re-run.

Comment: Yes, but I was suggesting a different approach, and hadn't realised you were carrying over the event.preventDefault(); I understand that you don't like this approach.

Comment: I tried replacing the event.preventDefault and synthesizeMouse with gContextMenu.initMenu(gBrowser) and, as expected, the normal menu is shown - i.e. it's not working, because when you click on newElement a different context menu is shown. Same goes with new ContextMenu(contextMenu, gBrowser).